# Adding class into method which only takes 1 parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to learn C# and have encountered a problem but I am not sure what it is. I am trying to call a stored procedure from an entity frame work, through a web service. However, I keep getting back an error:

```
CS1501: No overload for method 'CreateUser' takes 1 arguments
```

My sql data table is just a basic table (which works alright under other circumstances). I have put in a stored procedure (CreateUser) into my Entity datamodel. I have then created a Function (CreateUser) that has no return values.

This is the function, in my WebService.cs that I am trying to pass for which I get back the above error:

```
    public void AddUser(string Name, int Contact, string Email, string Password, bool Admin, string ImageURL)
    {
        UsersEntities entdb = new UsersEntities();

        NewUser newuser = new NewUser {
                      Name = Name,
                      ContactNo = Contact,
                      Email = Email,
                      Password = Password,
                      Admin = Admin,
                      ImageURL = ImageURL};
        entdb.CreateUser(newuser);
  }
```

Because of previous errors I had also created a class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class NewUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ContactNo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Admin { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

}
```

And from the normal page to call the Web Service (I am just trying to test it so I did not put in any other values):

```
protected void AddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomWebService cws = new CustomWebService();
    cws.AddUser("testName", 12345678, "testEmail", "testPassword", true, "testImage");
}
```

Would appreciate it if someone can help!!

Thanks in advance!

EDITED: Adding the CreateUser function:

```
        #region Function Imports

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">No Metadata Documentation available.</param>
    /// <param name="contactNo">No Metadata Documentation available.</param>
    /// <param name="email">No Metadata Documentation available.</param>
    /// <param name="password">No Metadata Documentation available.</param>
    /// <param name="admin">No Metadata Documentation available.</param>
    /// <param name="imageURL">No Metadata Documentation available.</param>
    public int CreateUser(global::System.String name, Nullable<global::System.Int32> contactNo, global::System.String email, global::System.String password, Nullable<global::System.Boolean> admin, global::System.String imageURL)
    {
        ObjectParameter nameParameter;
        if (name != null)
        {
            nameParameter = new ObjectParameter("Name", name);
        }
        else
        {
            nameParameter = new ObjectParameter("Name", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        ObjectParameter contactNoParameter;
        if (contactNo.HasValue)
        {
            contactNoParameter = new ObjectParameter("ContactNo", contactNo);
        }
        else
        {
            contactNoParameter = new ObjectParameter("ContactNo", typeof(global::System.Int32));
        }

        ObjectParameter emailParameter;
        if (email != null)
        {
            emailParameter = new ObjectParameter("Email", email);
        }
        else
        {
            emailParameter = new ObjectParameter("Email", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        ObjectParameter passwordParameter;
        if (password != null)
        {
            passwordParameter = new ObjectParameter("Password", password);
        }
        else
        {
            passwordParameter = new ObjectParameter("Password", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        ObjectParameter adminParameter;
        if (admin.HasValue)
        {
            adminParameter = new ObjectParameter("Admin", admin);
        }
        else
        {
            adminParameter = new ObjectParameter("Admin", typeof(global::System.Boolean));
        }

        ObjectParameter imageURLParameter;
        if (imageURL != null)
        {
            imageURLParameter = new ObjectParameter("ImageURL", imageURL);
        }
        else
        {
            imageURLParameter = new ObjectParameter("ImageURL", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        return base.ExecuteFunction("CreateUser", nameParameter, contactNoParameter, emailParameter, passwordParameter, adminParameter, imageURLParameter);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the method signature for `CreateUser`?

Comment: Please show us your code for your `UsersEntities.CreateUser()` function. It seems that it doesn't take the arguments you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for reply! @Simon Whitehead: where can I get the method signature?  I've added the auto generated function from the edmx cs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CreateUser method takes 6 parameters (name, contactNo, email, password, admin, ImageUrl), but you pass in the user, which is one argument. You need to do this:

```
NewUser newuser = new NewUser {
                  Name = Name,
                  ContactNo = Contact,
                  Email = Email,
                  Password = Password,
                  Admin = Admin,
                  ImageURL = ImageURL};
    entdb.CreateUser(newuser.Name, newuser.ContactNo, newuser.Email, newuser.Password, newuser.Admin, newuser.ImageURL);
```

or

modify the method to take only a NewUser parameter and in the method body, use the properties.